# Mapbox GL JS camera center directly move to user's location

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How to make camera center (starting position) directly move to user's location first, except press the "GeolocateControl" button in Mapbox GL JS?

Thanks!

```
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '...'

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    center: [23.7548053,62.5590779], // starting position
    zoom: 2,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
});

// Add geolocate control to the map.
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true
}));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the control is added to the map you can call `trigger`, see the documentation at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol#trigger

```
const geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true
});
map.addControl(geolocate);
geolocate.trigger();
```